# Why visiting saved page in Wayback Machine shows not archived?

Tags: wayback-machine

I want to save [https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~fwood/CS340/lectures/AD2.pdf](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Efwood/CS340/lectures/AD2.pdf) to [Wayback Machine](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Efwood/CS340/lectures/AD2.pdf).

It shows "A snapshot was captured. Visit page ..." however visiting that page shows "The Wayback Machine has not archived that URL.".

[image]

[image]

This situation not only happens to this link but also to many other links. The common point is that I was redirecting to figure 1 rather than snapshot after saving page.

I also tried to save the same page 45 minutes later, but nothing changes.

Comment: Sorry but this is off topic here. But I think you'll have to save a html page which contains a link to the pdf, otherwise the crawler might not save it.

Comment: on second thought, wayback machine just isn't thought to save single files. You shouldn't use it that way. Get a google drive or similar.